# What makes a NIB available to pick from the NIB Name drop down in XCode

Tags: xcode, ios

I am wondering what makes a NIB ( xib ) available to pick from the NIB Name menu.

I created a new UIViewController Subclass called Login.xib which comes with an XBI, implementation and header file, but it does not show up in that list.
I am just trying to understand what makes a nib available from that drop down ..

Thanks

[image: NIB Name]

Comment: Did you import the xib into your Xcode project?

Comment: yes Login.xib is part of my project along with Login.h and Login.m